# Interpolation and divergence of $n$-th derivative

Tags: approximation, interpolation

i have a curiosity.
Let's say i have a function $f \in C^{\infty}[a,b]$ such that there's a $x_0 in [a,b]$ that makes and $f(x_0) = 0$ and $a_n = f^{(n)}(x_0)$ diverges (i.e. $|a_n|=\infty$) could this affect somehow the accuracy of the approximation if i interpolate a function?

Answer (score 1):

The error of interpolation is usually expressed in terms of the higher derivatives of the interpolated function, similar to Lagrange  Remainder in terminated Taylor expansion which also sort of interpolation, actually extrapolation.
Namely, if $I_n(x)$ is an $n$'th order interpolant of $f(x)$ at points $\{(x_i,f(x_i)\}_{i=0}^n$  then 
$$e_n(x)=f(x)-I_n(x)\approx\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i)
$$

Therefore if the derivative $|f^{(n+1)}|$ doesn't exists or unbounded all the process of interpolation isn't valid anymore as the error term isn't defined or unbounded.

If all derivatives of order  $\leq n+1$ exists and bounded then your interpolation will work, otherwise - not.

Note that if you use too many points even if your function all required derivatives this won't be too good idea as the accuracy depends on a polynomial of a degree $n$ which grow up fast. Therefore practically one uses piecewise interpolations one per each few points (usually 2-3) of data,  or alternatively splines, the former can be considered the non smooth version of the later.
Therefore the smoothness requirements on $f$ are not too problematic.

---

**example for $f=3^x-1$**

```
>> x=linspace(-1,1,100); % uniform grid interpolation points
>> y=linspace(-1,1,2000);
>> f=@(x) 3.^x-1
>>
>>g=interp1(x,f(x),y,'linear');
>> norm(f(y)-g)

ans =

   0.002859258860134

>> g=interp1(x,f(x),y,'spline');
>> norm(f(y)-g)

ans =

     7.176506074372971e-08

>> g=interp1(x,f(x),y,'pchip');
>> norm(f(y)-g)

ans =

     5.546115531849058e-06
```

switching to chebyshev points (linear interpolation has a problem at end points)

```
>> x=cos((2*(1:100)-1)*pi/200);
>> g=interp1(x,f(x),y,'linear');
>> norm(f(y)-g)

ans =

   NaN

>> norm(f(y(2:end-1))-g(2:end-1))

ans =

   0.004192591427323


>> g=interp1(x,f(x),y,'spline');
>> norm(f(y)-g)

ans =

     7.481779555065644e-08

>> g=interp1(x,f(x),y,'pchip');
>> norm(f(y)-g)

ans =

     1.639113701734916e-05
```

Comment: For each $n$ i have $f^{(n)}$ bounded , so actually the interpolation process in general make sense. However is the sequence $f^{(n)}$ that diverges.

Comment: You don't interpolate with infinitely many points, don't you? If this is the case the only thing to care is for the bound of the derivative $n+1$.

Comment: They're a finite number of course, but i have been thinking to the fact that the "speed" of divergence of the derivative should affect the the error somehow.

Comment: the smoother the function the better\smaller the error, the expression of the error above determine the leading term, the lower order terms would affect, the actual error but less. Again, take an analogy of the error term in terminated Taylor expansion.
http://www.math.utah.edu/~mmedvin/Teaching/Math5610g6860/HandOuts/HO06Interpolation1.pdf

Comment: What do you mean with smoother with respect to my hypothesis? If you're referring to $f \in C^{\infty}$ what's the difference in a case when $\exists M \; \forall n \; |f^{(n)}| \leq M$ against $|f^{(n)}| \rightarrow +\infty$ but $\forall n \exists M_n |f^{(n)}| \leq M_n$. The second case i'm trying to say that every derivative is bounded, but the limit of such bounds diverges, it has to mean something.

Comment: It is also possible i'm saying a stupid thing with my example, but i think i made my point.

Comment: I refer to $f\in C^{n}$ - the greater $n$ the smoother function. The sequence you have in mind doesn't play significant role in analysis of interpolation in general. Unless you want to say that $f^n$ doesn't converge, which would mean Taylor expansion around some specific point in the given interval never converge? This would contradict $f\in C^{\infty}$, doesn't it? If you have a specific function in mind - it is the time to expose it.

Comment: I think you could take $f(x) = 3^x - 1$ defined in $I = [-1,1]$, for each $x \in I$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $f^{(n)}$ is bounded, however when $n$ diverges then $f^{(n)}(0)$ diverges too.

Comment: But i wasn't asking for it because i have a problem with a function with those properties, but because i was wondering if there's maybe some kind of properties or behaviour of the interpolant function, maybe not usually listed in the interpolation formula error you showed here early.

Comment: Do you know about Runge phenomena? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge's_phenomenon

Comment: Yes it's the oscillation problem of the interpolant, while the degree of the interpolant grows. But as far as i now, if instead of a single polynomial you use a piecewise law you don't have the problem anymore.

Comment: I mean probably i'm referring to some kind of more general interpolation problem (but not so general) you have a function expressed as linear combination of something $g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n \beta_j g_j(x)$ and i want that $\forall i \; g(x_i) = f(x_i)$ not necessarily i need to state that $g_i(x) = x^i$ but it could be a compact support function, a spline function as example. However surely i can say i'm looking at "polynomial laws" somehow.

Comment: did you try Chebyshev points with your function?

Comment: I got some more time, so note the edit. Now I totally don't know what the problem you looking for.

Comment: Never mind, i'll figure it out.

Comment: you may have problem  in case of $f^{(n+1)}>>\frac{P_n(x)}{(n+1)!}$. If you can find something special for the case you described, I guess no, I would like to know about it.